# How to find the most frequent places in list for certain list of elements?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, frequency-distribution

For example there is a list of elements

```py
[8,6,3,7,1,8,8,9,2,0,5,4,7,9,2,8,2,5,5,6,3,0,1,7,9,2,9,6,7,0,5,2,7,4,5,6,2,1,9,0,3,1,3,9,4,9,2,7,5,9,0,5,2,1,8,6,4]
```

I'm trying to find places (indexes) inside above list to find hits of second

```py
[1,4,3,8]
```

[image]

Is there common and elegant algorithms for that?

Comment: Could you clarify your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to find the most frequent place in text document for cloud of words

Comment: What is `most frequent place`?

Comment: Can you add an example with desired output for a small list? This would probably clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple visual representation of it using a plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst = [8,6,3,7,1,8,8,9,2,0,5,4,7,9,2,8,2,5,5,6,3,0,1,7,9,2,9,6,7,0,5,2,7,4,5,6,2,1,9,0,3,1,3,9,4,9,2,7,5,9,0,5,2,1,8,6,4]
target = [1,4,3,8]
result = [0]*len(lst)

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] in target:
        result[i] = 1

plt.step(range(len(lst)), result)
plt.show()
```

Giving the following, fairly easy to analyze result:

[image]

With the x-axis indicating the index in the list, and 1 represent in the target list and 0 not in it.

Comment: Now things are easier to dig! Thank you